# index out of range concerning CSV reader

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, csv, dictionary

I am trying to store the 2nd [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Acy5m.png) delimited spot in a csv UTF-8 file. My logic seems right but I KEEP GETTING an index out of range error which I can't seem to extrapolate. Here is my code:
    mylist_n = []
    with open(r'/home/main/Documents/AMCO/mypythonAMCO/ralco_Info.csv') as     csvfile:
        spamreader = csv.reader(csvfile,delimiter=',', quotechar='|')
        reader = csv.reader(csvfile)

```
    for row in spamreader:

        print(', '.join(row))
        mylist_n.append(row[1])
```

'''

---

```
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-46-5b4beea38798> in <module>
      6 
      7         print(', '.join(row))
----> 8         print(row[3]) #read the make -- write to list

IndexError: list index out of range
```

I know it has something to do with the output of row and a particular module/function call. That's all I need. I plan on getting position 3, storing it in a list and other respective positions related to make/model and eventually making a dictionary of dates with respective values to make the otherwise extraordinarily long name condensed.

[sam](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Acy5m.png)

Comment: Index numbering starts with `0`, therefore `3` means the 4th item.

Comment: sample input file will help ...

Comment: SO I just found out the csv has actually only 2 columns. Now I guess the questions is what IS row? What type of function is, what is its input and outputs and what respective functions can I use to turn row[1]  into a string of data to be stored in a list to be used in conjunction with the csvwriter.

Answer (score 0):

```
with open(r'/home/main/Documents/AMCO/mypythonAMCO/ralco_Info.csv') as csvfile:
    spamreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    #reader = csv.reader(csvfile)

    for row in spamreader:
        #print("->".join(csvfile))

        #print(row[1])

    make_n.append(row[1].lower)
    print("appended")
    print(row)
    print("\n")
```

To make a long story short, make sure to watch out for your comma's in CSV and I am to bolster my string manipulation and json skills tonight so I can parse through these individual strings within the list of which contain comma's from the source data.